# Align set of satellite images

Tags: geometry, georeferencing, satellite, alignment, distortion

I have a problem my set of four satellite images (4 different years of observations) of the same area are not aligned and more than that I see that there is a distortion problem also.

I found this problem when I stacked and matched these images to each other with the reference of the same building. (I did it in Photoshop - please don't bully me for this :-) I'm a newbie. ) However, when I checked other buildings - there were no matching. Then I realised that there is also a distortion problem [image]

that happened to my set of images. Therefore I can't align them straightaway.
[image]

[image]
On the example - a reference buildings are copied as a layer over other image and as you can see they are not matching.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello.
1. I have set of images of the same city for over 5 years. Images were taken with a 1-year difference. When I tried to match them in Photoshop and QGIs I couldn't do it. If I will try to match two images with reference with the same building at two images, other buildings will not match. Seems like there is a distortion of the image, and the geometric properties of the images are not matching.

Comment: Hello. @MrXsquared. I Used Photoshop and QGis. both of them didn't work well. Please see my comment above.

Comment: For the objects that are not aligned, are they just buildings, or are there objects at ground level that are not aligned as well? If it is only tall objects like buildings, this might just be due to the images being taken from different angles (and orthorectification then being done with something coarse like SRTM). In that case, there might not be any offset. Using the corners of buildings is tempting, but dangerous unless your orthorectification was done with a very detailed DEM. What satellite source are you using here?

Comment: Please don't comment on your own Question. Instead, [Edit] the Question to contain the requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [coregistration subpackage](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/tree/master/coregistration/eolearn/coregistration) in `eolearn`, which is intended for this sort of problem. I have not used it, but I think it could at least be a good reference for you.